# SQL OUTPUT entire row after update

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

With the following:

```
UPDATE ITS2_UserNames  
SET AupIp = @AupIp  
OUTPUT INSERTED.PrimaryKeyID
WHERE @Customer_ID = TCID AND @Handle_ID = ID
```

I get the primary key, but how do I get all columns?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this 
--TO get updated values of columns

```
 UPDATE ITS2_UserNames  
    SET AupIp = @AupIp  
    OUTPUT INSERTED.*
    WHERE @Customer_ID = TCID AND @Handle_ID = ID
```

--TO Get both new and old values

```
UPDATE ITS2_UserNames  
    SET AupIp = @AupIp  
    OUTPUT INSERTED.*,Deleted.*
    WHERE @Customer_ID = TCID AND @Handle_ID = ID
```

Comment: This works, although it creates duplicate column names. Explicitly naming the columns addresses that issue, e.g. `output Deleted.AupIp as [Before.AupIp], Inserted.AupIp as [After.AupIp], ...`.